# Google Play Console apk too big

Tags: android, google-play-console

I've just finished building my android app, but when I try to upload it to the Google Play Console it says the apk is too large. When looking it up it says you can add extension files, however I'm not sure how to now separate my app so I can upload an initial smaller size and then add the extension. Do I essentially need to create two apps, one which is the smaller base file and the other with all the extra features?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

Replace all of Images,Icons with vector drawable or

remove unnecessary Images from Drwable Folder

Step 2:

remove unnecessary  variable and library that are not used in code

Step 3: Add in Build.App

```
buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
   
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

}

Step 4:
Kindly Make Bundle for Play Console not Apk file

Comment: Thanks, I've added the code, think the issue is I need to create a dynamic feature module

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions for you which can help solve your issue:

1. Use the Android App Bundle

   - Google States:

     > In the second half of 2021, new apps will be required to publish with the Android App Bundle on Google Play. New apps larger than 150 MB must use either Play Feature Delivery or Play Asset Delivery.

     Therefore, you should use AAB files as they are the currently recommended publishing format, and soon the required one.
   - Android App Bundle also brings reduced download sizes for your users:

     > Google Play uses your app bundle to generate and serve optimized APKs for each device configuration, so only the code and resources that are needed for a specific device are downloaded to run your app. You no longer have to build, sign, and manage multiple APKs to optimize support for different devices, and users get smaller, more-optimized downloads.
   - More information: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
2. Use the APK/App Bundle Analyser

   - In Android Studio, go to Build > Analyse APK and select an APK or App Bundle file. Here you can find what files in your APK/App Bundle require the most storage space, and therefore you can reduce them to fit under the upload limit in the Google Play Console.
   - More info: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer
3. Shrink, obfuscate, and optimize your app:

   - In your app level build.gradle file add the following:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization
            minifyEnabled true

            // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the Android Gradle plugin.
            shrinkResources true

            // Removes unused code, and carries out other code optimisations
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                    'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

- More info: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

4. If none of the above solve the problem, then you will have to use Play Feature Delivery: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/play-feature-delivery